# Calling a method of a Java object passed as argument to hooked function in Frida

Tags: java, android, frida

I am trying to obtain the `SecretKey` passed to the `decryptAesCipherText` function. I hooked the function in Frida to try to print out the arguments when the method is called but since `SecretKey` is an object, all attempts to print it out give output as `[object Object]`. However the SecretKey object has a method getEncoded() which will return a byte array which can be printed out in hex format. How can I call this method from Frida and get the result?

The java function, I am hooking to is given below

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

private byte[] decryptAesCipherText(SecretKey secretKey, byte[] bArr) {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        instance.init(2, secretKey);
        return decryptCipherText(instance, bArr);
}
```

The javascript snippet (incomplete) to hook the function

```
var target_class = Java.use('com.reactlibrary.securekeystore.RNSecureKeyStoreModule');

target_class.decryptAesCipherText.overload('javax.crypto.SecretKey','[B').implementation = function(key, array){
        console.log("Inside decrypt aes");

        //Call getEncoded method on key to get byte array

        var ret = my_class.decryptAesCipherText.overload('javax.crypto.SecretKey','[B').call(this, key, array);
        return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can't call `getEncoded` on the `javax.crypto.SecretKey` interface.

Usually the `SecretKey` parameter is of type `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` and if you type cast the key parameter to `SecretKeySpec` you can can call `getEncoded()` and print the used key:

```
function encodeHex(byteArray) {
    const HexClass = Java.use('org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex');
    const StringClass = Java.use('java.lang.String');
    const hexChars = HexClass.encodeHex(byteArray);
    return StringClass.$new(hexChars).toString();
}

Java.perform(function x() {
    const target_class = Java.use('com.example.myapplication.MainActivity');
    target_class.decryptAesCipherText.overload('javax.crypto.SecretKey', '[B').implementation = function (key, array) {
        console.log("Inside decrypt aes");

        const secretKeySpec = Java.cast(key, Java.use('javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec'));
        const encodedKey = secretKeySpec.getEncoded();

        // print the key bytes as hex value
        console.log("KEY: " + encodeHex(encodedKey));

        var ret = my_class.decryptAesCipherText.overload('javax.crypto.SecretKey', '[B').call(this, key, array);
        return ret;
    }

});
```

Comment: in my case casting to `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` did not work! but casting to `java.security.Key` did work! anyway up :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly. Just a quick another question. Is it generally not possible to call methods on interfaces from Frida or just in this case ?

Comment: @AbinKPaul This is a good question. I don't have much experience with interfaces, but as you discovered that type casting to `java.security.Key` works. As it is a super interface of `SecretKey` and the interface that defines `getEncoded()`, it may be possible that in interfaces you have to use the interface that defines the method (may be an interface inheritance problem in Frida?).

Comment: Interface method has no body so we can't call them! It is a collection of abstract methods. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm. but casting to them is possible and as I casted `key` to `java.security.Key` I can call `kes`'s class methods. even in pure java casting `key` to `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` did not work!